# Writing an array into a text file

Tags: c, arrays, file, file-io

I am trying to write a character array into txt file. I can't find a mistake myself. This is supposed to work well but, this code doesn't write the array I want into txt file. Even if i want to overwrite on a txt file, It just writes blank character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(void){

   char temp[] = "Print newline, word, and byte counts for each FILE, and a total if more than one FILE is specified. With no FILE, or when FILE is a dash (\"-\"), wc operates on standard input. (A word is a non-zero-length sequence of characters delimited by white space.)";

   FILE *fpw = fopen("output.txt","w");
   if(ferror(fpw)) printf("Error");

   fputs(temp,fpw);
   fclose(fpw);

}
```

Comment: It'd perhaps write to the file only if the code were to compile.

Comment: Well, program works well. But, doesn't write anything into specified txt file.

Comment: `close(fpw);` ===> [`fclose(fpw);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fclose), and pay attention to your compiler warnings.

Comment: This works when I try it?

Comment: Well congrats. after the repeated edits your posted code no longer exhibits the original problem. I get a 253 byte text file called "output.txt" in the cwd. So much for that.

Comment: It is a mistake while writing on stackoverflow. Actually, I am writing a function which reads a txt file and makes an array from it. Then, I make all characters upper case. The last thing to do, writing on txt file. It just writes blank.

Comment: `if (ferror(fpw))` is not the right way to check if the `fopen` succeeded. You should use something like `if (!fpw) { perror("output.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: Problem was using close instead of fclose. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have " characters in temp string. Escape them with backslash, like this:

```
char temp[] "String with \"'s in it.";
```